# @CacheEvict annotation with SpEL works after Eclipse compile, but not after Ant compile

Tags: eclipse, spring, ant

### Problem

I have a class which uses Spring @CacheEvict annotations and embedded Spring Expression Language. When I allow this class to be compiled automatically by Eclipse, everything works fine. However, when I compile with an Ant task (either through Eclipse or from the command line), the resulting .class file doesn't work, and throws an Exception which seems like a red herring.

**My question**: How can I configure the Ant build so it generates working .class artifacts (so other developers can build my project without requiring Eclipse)? The configuration between Eclipse and Ant seem the same, but I must be missing some property somewhere.

### Versions

- Ant (bundled with Eclipse): org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730
- Eclipse: Juno Service Release 1, 20120920-0800
- JDK: 1.7.0_17
- JUnit: 4.10 (in /lib/ of project)
- O/S: Windows 7 64-bit
- Spring: 3.2.2

### Supporting Files

Because the problem is hard to describe without the project in front of you, I have boiled down my project to the bare minimum files needed to reproduce the issue:

**/src/sample/SampleAction.java**: Contains the method using the @CacheEvict annotation and SpEL.

```
package sample;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;

public class SampleAction {
    @CacheEvict(value = "sampleCache", allEntries = true, condition = "#string.bytes != null")
    public void triggerCache(String string) {
        System.out.println("triggerCache(" + string + ")");
    }
}
```

**/src/sample/SampleActionTest.java**: A unit test which works with Eclipse artifacts but fails with Ant artifacts.

```
package sample;
import org.junit.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"application.xml"})
public class SampleActionTest {
    @Autowired
    private SampleAction sampleAction;

    @Test
    public void testCacheMethod() {
        sampleAction.triggerCache("Definitely not a null string.");
    }
}
```

**/src/sample/application.xml**: Spring definition file for the caching and the action class.

```
<cache:annotation-driven />
<bean id="sampleAction" class="sample.SampleAction" />
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="sampleCache" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs**: Eclipse compiler settings (1.6 via 1.7.0_17):

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.inlineJsrBytecode=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.6
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.unusedLocal=preserve
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.6
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.lineNumber=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.localVariable=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.sourceFile=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.6
```

**/build.xml**: The Ant build which cleans, compiles, and runs the unit test that fails.

```
<path id="classpath.main">
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
</path>
<path id="classpath.test">
    <path refid="classpath.main" />
    <pathelement location="output/classes" />
</path>

<target name="compileFailure" description="Cleans, compiles, and runs a unit test, which fails.">
    <delete quiet="true" dir="output/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="output/classes" />      
    <copy tofile="output/classes/sample/application.xml" file="src/sample/application.xml" />
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="output/classes"
        classpathref="classpath.main" source="1.6" target="1.6" includeantruntime="false" />
    <junit printsummary="yes">
        <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
        <test name="sample.SampleActionTest" outfile="result" />
    </junit>
</target>
```

**/lib/*.jar**: Supporting libraries:

```
com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
junit-4.10.jar
spring-aop-3.2.2.jar
spring-beans-3.2.2.jar
spring-context-3.2.2.jar
spring-context-support-3.2.2.jar
spring-core-3.2.2.jar
spring-expression-3.2.2.jar
spring-test-3.2.2.jar
```

This stub project is also available as a ZIP archive, including supporting JAR files for Spring and JUnit:
[Minimal Eclipse Project](http://www.mediafire.com/download/r4d131n58n2hdm6/compilerDebug.zip)

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Open the "compilerDebug" project in Eclipse.
2. Allow Eclipse to automatically build the classes in the "sample" package. Either do a Project Clean/Build or open the Java files, edit the whitespace, and resave them. When compiled with Eclipse, output/classes/sample/SampleAction.class is 911 bytes.
3. Right-click on the "SampleActionTest" and choose "Run As... JUnit Test". **Test passes successfully.**
4. Open the build.xml file in the Ant view. Right-click on the "compileFailure" target  and choose "Run As... Ant Build". **Test fails** with "EL1007E:(pos 0): Field or property 'bytes' cannot be found on null" stack trace. When compiled with Ant, output/classes/sample/SampleAction.class is 694 bytes.

### Other Observations

1. I have tried adding *compiler="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"* to the "javac" task, in order to force Ant to use the Eclipse compiler, but the unit test still fails after this change. SampleAction.class is 696 bytes here.
2. If I remove the *condition* from the @CacheEvict annotation, the unit test passes with both compilers.
3. Setting source/target levels to 1.5 or 1.7 has no effect.
4. Forcing the Ant task to "run in the same JRE as workspace" has no effect.
5. Downloading a standalone Ant distribution (1.9.1) and running the Ant build completely isolated from Eclipse has no effect.
6. Replacing the @CacheEvict annotation with declarative XML configuration (using aspectjtools) has no effect.

Thanks in advance for helping to prevent my inevitable insanity from troubleshooting.

### Update

See answer provided below. Ant was not explicitly setting debug mode to **true** when compiling with **javac**. SpEL requires the extra debugging information to be included in the class files in order to correctly handle the annotations. Setting debug to true immediately corrected the issue.

```
<javac debug="true" [...] />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like SpEL need java compiler to set debug information in class file to work. I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301074/spring-cacheable-with-ehcache-spel-find-null-for-valid-object/24301241?noredirect=1#comment37566227_24301241) that resolved after I enabled debugging info to be generated in maven build. Eclipse compiler does this automatically.

Comment: This was the exact issue!