# How to get the value from one table using the foreign key from another table in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables : One is the **users** table and another is the **posts** table. Users table stores user's information and posts table stores relevant posts of the corresponding user, so user's id is now a foreign key in posts table .

In User.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private List<Post> posts;
```

and in Post.java

```
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn( name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

Here, everything is working well, tables have been structured as expected.

Now, when I hit a particular endpoint , "/posts" I need to retrieve all the posts from the posts table but this time not the user_id but the corresponding username from that id which is in users table. How to achieve that ?

Endpoint for retrieving all the posts(PostController.java).

```
@GetMapping("/posts")
public String getPosts(Model model) {
    List<Post> postList = postService.getPosts();

    model.addAttribute("posts", postList);

    return "Post";
}
```

PostService.java

```
public List<Post> getPosts() {
    return postRepository.findAllByOrderByIdDesc();
}
```

I am retrieving posts in Post.html using Thymeleaf.

Any informations regarding this would be helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried `post.getUser().getUserName()` ? Your `Post` entity is having `User` entity and not `user_id`, so when you do `post.getUser()`, you get whole `User` entity.

Comment: @LUC1F3R yes I have. It doesn't work. Says exception evaluating expression.

Comment: Please post stacktrace then.

Comment: @LUC1F3R this is the error ::: Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method getUsername() on null context object

Comment: Ok, please check if creating your own implementation of fetching all posts solves this issue, if not go through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173296/cacheevict-sometimes-missing-an-object-in-the-context-el1011e)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a default way to do this by repositories but here is how you can do it using HQL

add a function called `getPostsByUsername` in the repository and define it like so

```
@Query("SELECT p from POSTS p inner join p.user u where u.username=?1")
public List<Post> getPostsByUsername(String username);
```

note that the `u.username` the `username` is what the username field in the users table is named and not the actual column in the database.